# Evaluate $\int{\frac{\cos x}{2-\cos x}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

**Question:**

Evaluate $\int{\frac{\cos x}{2-\cos x}}dx$

**My Attempt:**

$\int{\frac{1-\tan^2\frac x2}{2(1+\tan^2\frac x2)-(1-\tan^2\frac x2)}}dx$

$=\int{\frac{1-\tan^2\frac x2}{1+3\tan^2\frac x2}}dx$

$=\int{\frac{2-\sec^2\frac x2}{1+3\tan^2\frac x2}}dx$

$=\int{\frac{2}{1+3\tan^2\frac x2}-\frac{\sec^2\frac x2}{1+3\tan^2\frac x2}}dx$

$=I_1-I_2$

$I_2=\frac2{\sqrt3}\tan^{-1}(\sqrt3\tan\frac x2)$

How to solve $I_1?$

Comment: The integrand is also just $\frac1{2\sec(x)-1}$

Comment: [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint%7B%5Cfrac%7B%5Ccos%20x%7D%7B2-%5Ccos%20x%7D%7Ddx%24&p=1) gives many related threads. Mostly this type of integrands appear in a definite integral over the period, when the standard procedure with residues works.

Comment: The textbook substitution $x=\tan(t/2)$, $dx=2\,dt/(1+t^2)$ also seems to work.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen that's for $I_2$, right?

Comment: For the original integral $$\int(-1+\dfrac2{2-\cos x})\,dx,$$ actually. No need for that gymnastics with trig identities. This substitution will convert a trigonometric integral into an integral of a rational function of $t$. True, trig identities underlying it ($\sin x=2t/(1+t^2)$, $\tan x=2t/(1-t^2)$). Anyway, the resulting rational function has a simple quadratic denominator, so you end up with a table integral. At least if (may be a big IF) the same tables that were used 40 years ago are still in use :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thank you, got it :)

Comment: Feel free to post it as an answer. There may still be close duplicates, but, to my surprise, Approach0 didn't offer a close match. There may be  one later simply because the early ones are largely definite integrals. I'm not gonna worry about it too much.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen did as directed, thanks:)

Answer (score 3):

$$I=\int{\frac{\cos x}{2-\cos x}dx}\\=-\int{\frac{-\cos x}{2-\cos x}dx}\\=-\int{\frac{2-\cos x-2}{2-\cos x}dx}\\=-\int{1-\frac2{2-\cos x}dx}\\=-x+2\int{\frac{\sec^2\frac x2}{1+3\tan^2\frac x2}dx}\\=-x+\frac4{\sqrt3}\tan^{-1}(\sqrt3\tan\frac x2)+c$$

This matches with the answer given by [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=integration+of+Divide%5B%5C%2840%29cosx%5C%2841%29%2C2-cosx%5D)